How does the amount of current coming from a wall socket change depending on whether it is a conductor or an insulator?
first of all, let me start by stating that my knowledge of electronics is at a very beginner level.
As far as I know, the electric current coming from the wall socket changes depending on whether there is resistance or not. If there is resistance, less current comes, if there is no resistance, more current comes.
So how does this happen? Shouldn't the electricity coming from the socket be constant whether there is resistance or not? There is a cable connected to the network and electricity is constantly coming from there? When there is an insulator at the end, how does the electric current decrease?

same way as a garden hose attachment limits the amount of water coming out; no attachment/resistance yields max amount of water in a timeframe, whereas a slip-n-slide's high resistance limits the amount of water coming out in a given timeframe.

The electric utility provides a constant voltage to the outlet - 120V or 240V give or take, depending on your region. All the loads you plug into your outlets, from a 2 watt night light to a 1750 watt space heater are added in parallel to each other, so the voltage at their input terminals is identical (ignoring slight drops from the resistance of the wires in your walls). The individual loads each have their own resistance - or effective resistance in the case of things like switch mode power supplies - that determines how much current they draw from the outlet; the 2W nightlight will have a much higher resistance than the space heater.
The outlet cannot "force" current to flow through a load, it simply provides a constant voltage and the load allows a certain amount of current to flow through it. An analogy would be the water supply to your house, with the water utility trying to maintain a constant pressure throughout your plumbing. You can turn on the faucet in your bathroom and get a small trickle to wash your hands or you can attach a hose to a spigot and get a powerful stream to wash your car.

The voltage at the outlet live hole is somewhat constant (120V or 230V depending where you live). The current, nonetheless, is determined by the appliance you connect to. As long as the current demanded by the appliance is less than the maximum current the outlet can provide, the outlet will happily provide the demanded current.
As a basic example, connecting a very demanding appliance (e.g. a washing machine) will demand quite some current out of the outlet, whereas connecting your alarm clock will demand very little. The voltage at the outlet remains somewhat constant, nonetheless.
As a more extreme example, if you were to short the live and neutral holes in your outlet (a very stupid thing to do, certainly), then, theoretically, the live wire should provide infinite current because 220V is connected directly to 0V. In real life, this current will be limited by the maximum the outlet can provide and the resistance of the shorting wire, but before that occurs a breaker will trip or a fuse will blow due to overcurrent.

If you short live and neutral, there is no earth leakage and nothing trips due to earth leakage.
